# Set dynamic state name in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am starting my adventure with React so it is a hard time for me, however I prepared such [pen](https://codepen.io/kalreg/pen/GxdgzW?editors=0111) for you to test. Here is a portion of code:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        settings: true,
        next: false,
    };

  }


   toggler(abc) {
     console.log(">>", abc)
     this.setState({
       next: !this.state.next
       /* {abc}: this.state.{abc} */
     }) 
     console.log(this.state.next)

   }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="kalreg">
      <MyButton name='settings' isActive={this.state.settings} type="settings" toggle={this.toggler.bind(this)}/>
      <MyButton name='settings2' isActive={this.state.settings} type="settings" toggle={this.toggler.bind(this)}/>
      <MyButton name='next' isActive={this.state.next} type="next" toggle={this.toggler.bind(this)}/>

    </div>)
  }

}

class MyButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  onChangeName(){
    console.log(this.props.type)
    if ( this.props.isActive ) { console.log("this one is active"); } else { console.log("ouch! it is not active, ignoring!"); return;}
    this.props.toggle(this.props.type);
  }

  render () {
    if ( this.props.isActive ) {
      return ( <div className="button notVisible" onClick={this.onChangeName.bind(this)}>{this.props.name}</div>)
    } else {
       return ( <div className="button visible" onClick={this.onChangeName.bind(this)}>{this.props.name}</div>)
    }
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

What I am trying to achieve is that when i press one of "settings" buttons (yellow) the "next" button becomes unclickable (green). There is a toggle function that every time I click settings button it turns on and off "next" button.

It works quite good, however it is just a draft of bigger project and i want to automate it a little bit.

As you can see I create my `<MyButton>` with both "isActive" and "type" props. But *isActive* holds what's inside this.state.settings while *type* is "settings". Instead of using two variables it would be great to pass only *type* of button to its component and component, depending on its type would check its parent's this.state.{type}. I used {type} because i would like to check it dynamically. Is that possible?

If so - how to do it?

My first attempt is to pass type from `<MyButton>` to `<App>` via `toggler` function. I named the variable "abc". I commented the way I wanted to do it because it doesn't work:

> {abc}: !this.state.{abc}

Any idea to solve this problem would be more than appreciated.
Kalreg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is somewhat unclear what you are trying to achieve here. If you want to wire the state dynamically based on type, as you wrote in code: `{abc}: !this.state.{abc}` each button would toggle itself, not the next button. In this case your syntax is a little incorrect, it will work if you write it like:

```
[abc]: !this.state[abc]
```

However as I said, in your example, this makes the `settings` button change the state for `this.state.settings` disabling itself instead of the next button.

Another note would be, that if it is not necessary for the `MyButton` component to know its own type for other reasons, it is unnecessary to pass it as a prop and than make the component pass it back as an argument (`this.props.toggle(this.props.type);`). You can simply define the toggle function in the parent as:

```
toggle={() => this.toggler("settings")}
```

without passing `type` as a prop.

Answer (score 0):

So basically we want to have the `settings` and `settings2` buttons, and when we click on them, they toggle the state of the `next` button by making it un-clickable (green).

So if that is our goal, then

- we don't need an `isActive` prop for the settings button. (Because it's always going to be active no matter what)
- We also don't need to have a `toggle` prop on the Next button. (Because clicking the next button isn't supposed to toggle anything)
- Instead of having two variables in the state why not just have one and then use that to determine the `isActive` prop of the next button?

The component would look like this:

```
constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            nextIsActive: false,
        };
    }

    toggler() {
        this.setState({
            nextIsActive: !this.state.nextIsActive
        }) 

        console.log(this.state);
    }

    render() {
        const {nextIsActive} = this.state

        return (
            <div className="kalreg">
                <MyButton name='settings' isActive={true} type="settings" toggle={this.toggler.bind(this)}/>
                <MyButton name='settings2' isActive={true} type="settings" toggle={this.toggler.bind(this)}/>
                <MyButton name='next' isActive={nextIsActive}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

That way you don't have to have 2 state properties that you have to dynamically update because it adds more complexity to your application.

You can see the finished product here: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/FrenchMajesty/pen/aYGpYE)